# Generating multilevel JSON using C# with multiple records

Tags: c#, json.net

I want to create the following JSON object string using C#. I am getting data from the database to set the data.

```
{
   "markers":[
      {
         "articles":[
            {
               "ID":3759,
               "post_type":"report",
               "post_title":"No",
               "post_url":"/report/",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "institution_name":"Georgetown"
                  },
                  {
                     "journal_name":"Jama"
                  },
                  {
                     "lead_author":{
                        "id":2214,
                        "name":"Kelly",
                        "slug":"dr",
                        "description":"director",
                        "image_object":{
                           "thumbnail":"test.png",
                           "thumbnail-width":150,
                           "thumbnail-height":150,
                           "medium":"test.png",
                           "medium-width":300,
                           "medium-height":300,
                           "medium_large":"test.png",
                           "medium_large-width":361,
                           "medium_large-height":361,
                           "large":"test.png",
                           "large-width":361,
                           "large-height":361
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "location":{
            "name":"location",
            "include_on_map":true,
            "address":null,
            "lat":null,
            "lng":null
         }
      },      
      {
         "articles":[
            {
               "ID":1893,
               "post_type":"report",
               "post_title":"Controls",
               "post_url":"/report/",
               "fields":[
                  {
                     "institution_name":"System"
                  },
                  {
                     "journal_name":"World"
                  },
                  {
                     "lead_author":{
                        "id":1019,
                        "name":"Hardesty",
                        "slug":"hardesty",
                        "description":"",
                        "image_object":{
                           
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         ],
         "location":{
            "name":"location",
            "include_on_map":true,
            "address":"USA",
            "lat":"38.12345",
            "lng":"-70.12345"
         }
      }
   ],
   "params":{
      "path":"",
      "raw_path":null,
      "page":1,
      "lang":"en",
      "items":9,
      "type":"",
      "term":null,
      "offset":0,
      "direction":"DESC",
      "order":"date",
      "currentpagenumber":[
         ""
      ]
   }
}
```

Could you please help me to create the json output using foreach loop?

Below is the code i am having currently.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JSON
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string jsonString = string.Empty;

            Root root = new Root()
            {
                Markers = new List<Marker>
                {
                     new Marker()
                     {
                           Articles = new List<Article>
                           {
                               new Article()
                               {
                                    ID=1234,  
                                    PostTitle="Test",
                               }
                           },
                           Location = new Location()
                           {
                                 Name="Location" ,
                                 Address="USA",
                           }
                     }
                },

                Params = new Params()
                {
                    Page = 1,
                }

            };

            jsonString = JsonString(root);

            Console.WriteLine(jsonString);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static string JsonString(Root model)
        {
            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
            return jsonString;
        }
    }
}




using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JSON
{
    class JsonModel
    {
    }

    public class ImageObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("thumbnail")]
        public string Thumbnail { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thumbnail-width")]
        public int ThumbnailWidth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thumbnail-height")]
        public int ThumbnailHeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium")]
        public string Medium { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium-width")]
        public int MediumWidth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium-height")]
        public int MediumHeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium_large")]
        public string MediumLarge { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium_large-width")]
        public int MediumLargeWidth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("medium_large-height")]
        public int MediumLargeHeight { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("large")]
        public string Large { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("large-width")]
        public int LargeWidth { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("large-height")]
        public int LargeHeight { get; set; }
    }

    public class LeadAuthor
    {
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("slug")]
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image_object")]
        public ImageObject ImageObject { get; set; }
    }

    public class Field
    {
        [JsonProperty("institution_name")]
        public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("journal_name")]
        public string JournalName { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lead_author")]
        public LeadAuthor LeadAuthor { get; set; }
    }

    public class Article
    {
        [JsonProperty("ID")]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("post_type")]
        public string PostType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("post_title")]
        public string PostTitle { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("post_url")]
        public string PostUrl { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fields")]
        public List<Field> Fields { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("include_on_map")]
        public bool IncludeOnMap { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lat")]
        public string Lat { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lng")]
        public string Lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Marker
    {
        [JsonProperty("articles")]
        public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("location")]
        public Location Location { get; set; }
    }

    public class Params
    {
        [JsonProperty("path")]
        public string Path { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("raw_path")]
        public object RawPath { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("page")]
        public int Page { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lang")]
        public string Lang { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public int Items { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("term")]
        public object Term { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("offset")]
        public int Offset { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("direction")]
        public string Direction { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("order")]
        public string Order { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("currentpagenumber")]
        public List<string> Currentpagenumber { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("markers")]
        public List<Marker> Markers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("params")]
        public Params Params { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you expecting to transform information about devices into data about blog posts?

Comment: Do you _need_ to use the structure above? It would be much easier if you used an array of objects, rather than having 'First' and 'Second' objects, which will be much harder to serialize

Comment: Hi @stuartd I have updated the exact JSON what i need to output. Kindly check once.

Comment: So can't you just paste that into https://json2csharp.com ?

Comment: I tried that (after you mentioned, i wasn’t aware earlier). It generates class/model which I can manage to create as well. I am struggling to set data for this nested structure in main program in for each loop.

Comment: *I am struggling to set data for this nested structure in main program in for each loop.* - then please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing where you are stuck. Your current c# code looks nothing like the JSON at the beginning of your question so it's not clear how the question should be answered.

Comment: Hi @dbc I have updated the question with my latest Model and Main program. The place where i stuck is, to add multiple nodes (articles/location) under markers